# Will VS 2012 support classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic, visual-studio-2012

I have a classic asp application that I've been developing with Visual Studio 2010 and it's been the best version of Visual Studio for that yet. Will Visual Studio 2012 continue supporting classic asp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 RC for ASP Classic development and it is still supported.